# How to spy on a Mac from a PC

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, screen-sharing

I have a desktop running Windows 7 and a Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard.  If someone is using my Macbook Pro, and from my Windows 7 machine I want to see what they see on their screen, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are running Mac OS X 10.4 or higher, turn on Screen Sharing, and make sure that Allow screen sharing through VNC is turned on.

Once that is done, you can connect via any VNC tool, from any platform.

Comment: In Snow Leopard that is: System Preferences » Sharing » Screen Sharing, button Computer Settings and then "VNC viewers may control screen with password ..."

Comment: This may display a menu extra notifying the user they are being watched. If you want invisible observation, you may need to do this through the Remote Desktop controls--they have an option to disable the "show when being observed" option, and includes a VNC option. Basically a superset of the Screen Sharing panel.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) . also you can even try out with [Logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/US/solutions/personal/) on both Win7 and [Mac](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/) too.

Comment: Logmein announces you are remoting into a pc.